# Generating html report in workspace with Taurus and Performance plugin in Jenkins

Tags: performance, jenkins, jmeter, report, taurus

I am using Taurus with Performance plugin to run my Jmeter tests in Jenkins. Although I get the Performance report in Jenkins but I am not getting an html file generated in the workspace which I can send in the email body as report. Currently in the email I am just sending a link to the report but I do not want users to click on the link to go to the Jenkins Performance report, I need the report in the email body.
Please let me know if there is any way to get the html report in the email body or convert aggregate_report.xml file to html in the workspace?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can convert .xml result file into HTML using i.e. [JMeter Ant Task](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/tags/v2_2/extras/JMeter%20Ant%20Task.html)

1. Configure your JMeter result file to end with `.jtl` rather than with `.xml`, i.e `aggregate_report.jtl`
2. Configure Jenkins to convert .jtl into .html using aforementioned Ant task by adding the next [Jenkins pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) step:

   ```
   node {
       dir('/path/to/jmeter/extras') {
           bat "ant -Dtest=aggregate_report xslt-report"
           step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: 'aggregate_report.html', fingerprint: true])
       }
   }
   ```

More information: [Running a JMeter Test via Jenkins Pipeline - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-test-jenkins-pipeline-tutorial)